# Get variable or object from IBAction method

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, ios6

I have been reading, googling and watching Lynda videos to find the answer for this the last couple days.  I haven't found a good answer yet.

This seems like it should be pretty simple.  With normal methods I can pass variables.  But with IBAction being (void) I cant figure out how to get a variable to another method.

Here are some simple examples of what I would like to do:

```
- (IBAction)treeButton:(id)sender {
    int test = 10;
}


-(void)myMethod{
     NSLog(@"the value of test is %i",test);
}
```

This what I really want to have work.  I am try to have a button set the initial location that I want to store and use in another method.

```
- (IBAction)locationButton:(id)sender {
    CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc]
       initWithLatitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
       longitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
}


-(void)myMethod{
     NSLog(@"the value of test is %i",test);
     NSLog(@"location 1 is %@",loc1);
}
```

Any suggestions to lead me in the right direction would be great.  I have read and watched videos on variable scope, instance varaibles etc.  Just not understanding what I need to do here

Comment: Perhaps re-watch one of the instance variable videos? loc1 needs to be an instance variable, at the moment it's scope is restricted to your method.

Comment: Create a new instance variable namely loc1 in your controller and assign it a value everytime certain IBAction is triggered and use it from other method. Its that simple.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  esqew's answer showed me that I was redefining the instance variable inside my method.  Guess that was easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `myMethod` to accept the parameters you need:

```
- (void)myMethod:(CLLocation *)location {
    NSLog(@"location 1 is %@", location);
}
```

Invoke it something like so:

```
- (IBAction)locationButton:(id)sender {
    CLLocation *loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc]
       initWithLatitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
       longitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
    [self myMethod:loc1];
}
```

---

If you need it to be accessible by multiple methods or at different points in the code, I recommend creating an instance variable for `loc1` in your `@interface` declaration.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject {
    CLLocation *loc1;
}
```

In your method, instead of re-declaring it, you'd just set it:

```
loc1 = [[CLLocation alloc]
       initWithLatitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.latitude
       longitude:_locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude];
```

In `myMethod`, just access it:

```
- (void)myMethod{
    NSLog(@"location 1 is %@", loc1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick concise answer.  I spent 3 days trying to figure this out before asking a question here (learned a lot).  I didn't realize that I was re-declaring the instance variable inside my method.  Makes complete sense now.  Thanks!!!